"Error: Could not invoke RNPhotoEditor.SDK.Present in React Native project"
I'm encountering an error in my React Native project when trying to use the PhotoEditor SDK. The error message I'm receiving is

Could not invoke RNPhotoEditor.SDK.Present

I'm unsure what might be causing this issue, as the feature was working properly before.
Here are some details about my project setup:

PhotoEditor SDK version: "react-native-photoeditorsdk": "2.13.0",
Platform: [iOS/Android/both]
I've checked my installation and followed all the steps in the documentation for integrating the PhotoEditor SDK into a React Native project. I've also ensured that the necessary permissions are set up correctly.
Despite this, I'm still encountering the error. I've searched online for solutions but haven't found any that address this specific issue.

Is there additional stack-trace that might reveal whether the class just couldn't be found, whether there was a compatibility issue or whether there was some other problem when constructing an instance of the photo editor?
